# Firestore add collection

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to store form document to my Firebase collection (cloud Firebase). I'm worrkin with angular and one service:

```
crearNorma( $normas) {
    this.normasCollection = this.db.collection('norma');
    this.$normas = this.normasCollection.valueChanges().pipe(map( 
        (resp: NormaModel[]) => resp.map( 
            ({nombre, deporte, minValor, criterio, coeficiente})  => ({nombre, deporte, minValor, criterio, coeficiente}) 
        )
    ))this.normasCollection.add($normas);
}
```

Firebase return error problem because hi needs and object and i he send and array.
How couldi Convert in array? I tried with pipe and map.

The service only works with this example, but it's literal example.

```
const newNorma =  {
    nombre: 'albero',
    deporte: 'btt',
    criterio: 'desnivel',
    minValor: 23,
    coeficiente: 2.3,
};
this.normasCollection.add(norma);
```

Comment: how is normas conformed? pass a named array, where each field has a name

Comment: Are you getting the data over http or it is generated in your application?

Comment: norma is an interface:

    export interface NormaModel {
    id?: string;
    nombre: string;
    deporte: string;
    minValor: number;
    coeficiente: number;
    criterio: string;
}

Comment: the data is over Firebase store